# Where do these margins come from?

Tags: android, printing

I'm writing a proprietary `PrintService` and I encounter some problems on the received PDF file generated by the Android `PrintManager`.
I suppose some print attributes are not set correctly.

Here is the simple code I use to print something. It's my test application:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    // I also set padding to 0 in case....
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // So I tried to set html margin/padding to 0 but it doesn't change the print preview
    String summary = "<html><body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0; width:100%; height: 100%;\">" +
            "-------------------------------------<br/>" +
            "I'm just printing something!<br/>" +
            "-------------------------------------<br/>" +
            "</body></html>";
    webView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");

}

public void createWebPrintJob(View view) {

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    if (printManager != null) {
        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name);
        PrintJob job = null;

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter =
                webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

        if ((job = (printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build()))) != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Job succesfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Now on the `PrintService` side, below is how I initialize the printer capabilities:

```
@Override
public void onStartPrinterStateTracking(@NonNull PrinterId printerId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartPrinterStateTracking");
    PrinterInfo printer = findPrinterInfo(printerId);

    if (printer != null) {

    PrintAttributes.MediaSize rollSize = new PrintAttributes.MediaSize("Roll58mm", "Roll58mm", 1892, 5676);
    PrintAttributes.Margins rollMargins = new PrintAttributes.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        PrinterCapabilitiesInfo capabilities = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId)
                .addMediaSize(rollSize, true)
                .setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME)
                .addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("200dpi", "paperRoll", 203,203), true)
                .setMinMargins(rollMargins)
                .build();

        printer = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printer)
                            .setCapabilities(capabilities)
                            .build();
        List<PrinterInfo> printers = new Vector<>();
        printers.add(printer);
        addPrinters(printers);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find requested printer !");
    }
}
```

Here is the printing preview and so I don't understand why I get margins or padding, around my text whereas I specified 0 for all.

[image: my printing preview]

So why do I see margins here as I specified 0 for all?

-**EDIT**-
I've updated my `onCreate` method according to some posts talking about similar problem bu without success!

Comment: Can you post your XML `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: @ThomasMary what for please as I programmatically create a webview?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you print from any other app? How is the printed output look like (assuming you're using a physical printer)? To me this just seems like a preview issue nothing else

Comment: @nonos, I tried to print a bitmap from the Gallery and I don't see these margins. It seems to exists on the WebView only but nothing helps to remove it.

Comment: @fralbo did you find any solution? i have similar problem if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-not-display-full-content-with-images

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi, I switched to something else and unfortunately don't really remember everything but AFAIR, according to my tests and despite what is explained in the doc, the displayed represents the printed area and not the paper view so we don't have to specify margins. As I wanted to use the full paper size to print my text, I didn't try to understand how to really manage the margins... Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by adding css styles to HTML.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page
{
    size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}

html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
}

body
{
    margin: 0mm; /* margin you want for the content */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that there are elements inside the layout (or the layout itself) in wich you are inserting your PDF with margins set.

Comment: certainly but what, I found few posts about this problem and I've updated my code to see but it doesn't change anything. I precise that I don't render the webview in my app, I only use it to create a pdf rendering as explained in my code.